# Intersect does not retrieve list as expected

Tags: c#, ienumerable, intersect, enumerable

I have two lists, the first one contains a lot of items, and the second one contains one item that also exists on first list.

And I was wrote code to check if the first list contains all second list items and retrieve Boolean value.

My issue is the `Intersect` retrieve empty list which means there's no intersect between two lists that I compare (so the value will be false always).

My code line:

```
var res = retrieved.ResponeDataList.Intersect(listOrObj.ResponeDataList).Count() == listOrObj.ResponeDataList.Count();
```

listOrObj.ResponeDataList contains one item with value:

```
"{{DapperRow, id = '1', name = 'testEntity', diagram_id = '1', creation_date = '1/27/2022 3:00:04 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}".
```

I was tried to get the value of the first object from both lists and fill them on testing lists and it's work fine as the following:

```
List<dynamic> a = new List<dynamic>();
a.Add("{{DapperRow, id = '1', name = 'testEntity', diagram_id = '1', creation_date = '1/27/2022 3:00:04 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}");
a.Add("{{DapperRow, id = '2', name = 'testEntity2', diagram_id = '5', creation_date = '1/27/2022 5:10:27 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}");
a.Add("{{DapperRow, id = '3', name = 'testEntity3', diagram_id = '110', creation_date = '1/27/2022 10:22:08 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}");
a.Add("{{DapperRow, id = '4', name = 'testEntity4', diagram_id = '72', creation_date = '1/27/2022 11:01:52 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}");
List<dynamic> b = new List<dynamic>();
b.Add("{{DapperRow, id = '1', name = 'testEntity', diagram_id = '1', creation_date = '1/27/2022 3:00:04 PM', created_by = '7', modification_date = '1/27/2022 1:04:06 PM', modified_by = '7', deletion_date = '1/27/2022 1:07:07 PM', deleted_by = '7', mapped_table = 'TE        '}}");
var rr = a.Intersect(b).Count() == b.Count(); //value = true
```

Any help?

**EDIT:** For test I tried to add range from second list to the first list and the `Intersect` worked for new added items only, Although the added items already exists before on the first list.

```
retrieved.ResponeDataList.AddRange(listOrObj.ResponeDataList);
var res = retrieved.ResponeDataList.Intersect(listOrObj.ResponeDataList).Count() == listOrObj.ResponeDataList.Count();
```

both lists type is `List<dynamic>` and I'm sure that the all items in second list already exists in first list before try to add range.

Comment: In you sample code the `a.Intersect....` returns as many rows as there are in `b`. So you did not provide a good [mre]. Can you [edit] your question, and improve it (show example which returns false, but should (in your opinion) return true) ?

Comment: @Luuk I was update the test code with correct items and also its work fine

Comment: Have u tried `a.Any(x => b.Any(y => y == x))` instead of `Intersect` method?

Comment: @mahooresorkh same thing

Comment: @Luuk I was edit the question with changes may help

Comment: @mahooresorkh I was edit the question with changes may help

Comment: Is the "value" a string or is that the string representation of that object. My guess is the actual type does not define value equality.

Comment: @DStanley The type of two list same, and each object and its attributes inside both lists is same.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the attributes are the same if the actual type (not `dynamic`) don't define value equality. What is the _actaul_ typoe of the objects (`dynamic` just means that you don't know the type at coding-time).

Comment: I think you are comparing objects in the first case. But in the second case, you compare text strings. In the first case, because these items point to different parts of the memory, they will not be equal, even though all the values ​​of its properties are equal.

Comment: @mahooresorkh you are right, but how can I solve this issue

Comment: What value do you get from `listOrObj.ResponeDataList[0].id` ?